# How do I hide a text box based on a value in another text box?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a text box that has this in it "More Previous Addresses and Contact Info". Underneath it, I have a text box that will record the text that the applicant will fill in if they have a previous address, if they don't have any previous addresses, I don't want to first text box to show up. The datatype for the second text box is VARCHAR.

I tried to hide the first text box using this expression in the "Show of hide based on an expression" box:

=iif(First(Fields!PAddressMore.Value, "MainQuery") IsNothing, True, False) but it is giving me an error.

I've tried using "CountRows", but I think that only works with tablix, which this is not.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsNothing` is a function, so you can't use it like that. It does however return true or false so you don;t actually need the `IIF()` at all.

try this

```
=IsNothing(First(Fields!PAddressMore.Value, "MainQuery"))
```

This will return true if the `PAddressMore` column is `NULL` in your dataset. If this is set as the `Hidden` property expression then it should give you what you want.